# Working around unset "length" property on partial functions created with lodash's partialRight

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I'm working with [MomentTimezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) for time manipulation in the browser.

I am using TypeScript and [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) too.

I have some `accountTimezone` set on the `window` containing the authenticated user's preferred timezone. I am trying to create a helper method `localMoment()` that will accept any of [the many signatures of `moment.tz()`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a3528daaf0b06c5ed3864bf4c28a0c438fd374a3/types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts#L21-L32), appending this `window.accountTimezone` as the final `timezone: string` argument.

It seems [`partialRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partialRight) may be what I'm looking for.

```
const localMoment = partialRight(moment.tz, window.accountTimezone);
```

The problem I'm having has to do with this note from the lodash docs:

> **Note:** This method doesn't set the "length" property of partially applied functions.

Specifically, for a call like `localMoment('2019-08-01 12:00:00')`, TypeScript complains that `localMoment()` was provided 1 argument, but expects zero.

**How can I keep TypeScript happily understanding a call to `localMoment()` should look like a call to `moment.tz()` via the `MomentTimzone` interface, while avoiding this arity confusion from the use of `partialRight()`?**

---

I considered something like this as an alternative, but don't know how to type `...args` to keep TypeScript happy.

```
const localMoment = (...args): Moment => moment.tz(...args, window.accountTimezone);
```

Comment: In order to obtain the behavior you want, it would have to detect all of the possible signatures of `localMoment` based on all of the possible signatures of `moment.tz` and it looks like the lodash TypeScript definition file doesn't support that (it believes the signature is static and equals to `<T1, R>(func: Function1<T1, R>, arg1: T1): Function0<R>;`). Either the lodash TypeScript definition file is misconceived, or it's a TypeScript limitation, according to me, so I don't believe there is much to do on your side, except ignoring TypeScript errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this. You either have to opt out of typing or redeclare an interface of your own.

Typescript himself can't do this and just opt for the "good-enough" solution of declaring a bunch of different signatures:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/function.d.ts#L1147

Even if you somehow manage to manipulate the typescript interface, I doubt you could handle the other methods (`zone`, `add`, `link`, ...) which don't have a timezone parameter:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts#L20

The best you can achieve is avoiding duplicating the whole interface using the `Pick` utility type:

```
type CurriedMomentTimezone = Pick<moment.MomentTimezone, 'zone' | 'add' | 'link' | 'load' | 'names' | 'guess' | 'setDefault'> & {
    (): moment.Moment;
    (date: number): moment.Moment;
    (date: number[]): moment.Moment;
    (date: string): moment.Moment;
    (date: string, format: moment.MomentFormatSpecification): moment.Moment;
    (date: string, format: moment.MomentFormatSpecification, strict: boolean): moment.Moment;
    (date: string, format: moment.MomentFormatSpecification, language: string): moment.Moment;
    (date: string, format: moment.MomentFormatSpecification, language: string, strict: boolean): moment.Moment;
    (date: Date): moment.Moment;
    (date: moment.Moment): moment.Moment;
    (date: any): moment.Moment;
}

localMoment = _.partialRight(moment.tz, this.accountTimezone) as CurriedMomentTimezone;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had not previously heard about TypeScript's utility types, so I have some reading to do. This doesn't just suppress the error for me - it still lets my editor provide me context beyond  "a series of `any` arguments" for what `localTime()` is doing with the arguments I'm passing in.

Comment: I do want to point out that I have to remove the `timezone: string` args from the last two lines of the `CurriedMomentTimezone` type definition. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

These signatures make TypeScript happy:

```js
const localMoment = (...args: any[]): moment.Moment => moment.tz.apply(this, [...args, this.accountTimezone]);


const localMoment2 = _.partialRight(moment.tz, this.accountTimezone) as (...args: any[]) => moment.Moment;
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-r1h2tq?embed=1&file=index.ts

Since one moment.tz signature accepts a parameter of `any` type, it's not much use to create a stricter type than `any[]` unless you create local overloads for every moment.tz overload.

Comment: Thanks. While this does work for me, I prefer the verbose-ness of the version provided by @Nicolas Reynis - it gives a clearer indication in my editor as to what localTime()` is looking for. I very much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following function type signature to your `localMoment` definition:

```js
const localMoment: (moment: string) => (string | undefined) = partialRight(moment.tz, window.accountTimezone);
```

For your alternative code, the following should work using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const localMoment: (args: string[]) => (string | undefined) = (args: string[]) => moment.tz(...args, window.accountTimezone);
```

You can read more about "Typing Functions in TypeScript" [in this blog post](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typing-functions-in-typescript).